# What if I want to see answers for other jurisdictions on someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, jurisdiction

I would love to see the answers for the U.S. to this question posed for the U.K.: [What liabilities do the police/CPS have if you are found innocent?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/what-liabilities-do-the-police-cps-have-if-you-are-found-innocent)

Should I post it as a new question?

Some semblance of cohesion can be maintained by noting the original question in derived questions.  But I'm wondering if this would create an undesirable proliferation of questions.  E.g., "OK, now what about Germany?  Now what about Japan?"

I was wondering if it might be better to edit the original question to say, "Originally asked about the U.K., but somebody wants answers also for U.S., Germany, and Japan..."?

Answer (score 13):

The benefit of asking jurisdiction based variants as separate questions is that the best answers for that specific variation of the question can rise to the top.

If a question has answers that address a large country and a small country the answers for the less trafficked locale will be buried beneath potentially lower quality answers from the larger locale.

Including the jurisdiction in the title can help to keep the titles from appearing to be duplicates.