# What clarity does this question need?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question was close voted for clarity. There was a previous question like this which was deleted and [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/is-any-youtuber-required-to-block-videos-for-people-below-18-even-if-the-videos) asked:

> #### Is any YouTuber required to block videos for people below 18 even if the videos are good for people of any age due to data being privacy laws?
>
> Many countries have data privacy laws that require special care for
> data of people below the years age of 18. 
>  A Youtube video upto a
> certain point of time as of writing and as far as I know cannot be
> geographicaly restricted to try to not do business in certain
> countries . 
>  Moreover some of these countries extend laws to all
> their citizen so geoblocking should not help. 
>  Youtube collects
> data as of writing for their use and to facilitate ads for youtubers.
>
>  Youtube allows blocking below 18 for content  very impolite ..
>
>  Should youtubers who upload content above any length and of
> content of general  ( What I mean by this is general educational
> content ) also age restrict below 18 ? 
>  This is so that they do
> not reach the videos so no data collection ! 
>  I mean shouldn't all
> youtuber be liable for not age restricting their videos to below 18
> because that might lead to data collection from them ?

Comment: That question doesn't seem closed....

Comment: Please link to the closed question.

Comment: A close vote was cast the question was not closed .

Comment: I deleted that question but moderators can still see .

Comment: There is no guarantee that the person who cast that close vote can see deleted questions.  It requires 4x as much reputation to see deleted questions as it does to cast close votes.  I added the text of the question you're asking about to this one so that people can see.

Comment: Note this related meta question: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/when-would-a-legal-question-need-not-include-jurisdiction

Answer (score 1):

It needs *a specific law or jurisdiction*.

If you want to know if someone is liable for something, or if something violates a law, you need to say what law you're asking about, or at least what *country* you're asking about.  A vague assertion about "many countries," without examples, doesn't really help.

As is, people trying to answer are forced to consider how a hypothetical law in some country *might* possibly work, which isn't really answerable.

Comment: added complication: some laws are governing in a language that has totally different syntax than a machine translation would imply!

Comment: This is the narrowed down question : https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60892/youtube-made-for-kids . It is a bit international  question .